# linux veth use existing peer interface

Tags: linux, networking, routing, bridge

I have a sit tunnel interface which I want to transparently connect with one end of a veth pair so that everything that drops out of the tunnel interface flows through the veth interface and vice versa.

Remote tunnel interface (fd50::1) --sit tunnel--> Local tunnel interface --> veth interface --veth pipe--> veth interface peer (fd50::2)

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance